# How to distinguish between two routes: one for parameterless action and one for the index action with one parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller with multiple actions and I set up the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "MyCustomRoute",
   url: "MyTarget/{option}",
   defaults: new { controller = "MyTarget", action = "Index", option = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The main idea here is to call the `Index` action of the `MyTarget` controller as default, passing only the argument in the URL.

The lightweight controller looks like this:

```
public class MyTargetController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string option)
    { ... }

    public ActionResult FirstAction()
    { ... }

    public ActionResult SecondAction(param list)
    { ... }
}
```

The `MyCustomRoute` is set to map `MyWebsite/MyTarget/randomOption` to the `Index` action, passing `randomOption` as the `option` parameter. The problem is that this route catches all the other actions too: `MyWebsite/MyTarget/FirstAction` and `MyWebsite/MyTarget/SecondAction` (ignore the lack of parameters) are mapped to the `Index` action and their names are routed as the `option` parameter.

I don't want to change the URL into something like `MyWebsite/MyTarget/Index/randomOption`. Is there a clear way for distinguishing between a default action with one parameter and other actions, which may or may not have parameter?

**EDIT:** the following workarounds can be implemented, balancing the advantages and disadvantages:

- all actions except `Index` can be moved to a *helper* controller: creates two separate controllers processing the same logic;
- a custom route constraint can be created, that checks if the parameter value corresponds to the name of an existing action (except `Index`): needs a way of storing the names of the actions and needs the list to be updated every time a new action is added to the controller (Reflection might be a better approach).

None of the above workarounds seam to be elegant and without any "special" caring.

Comment: Maybe you could add a route constraint for the first route that excludes values like "FirstAction" and "SecondAction" for the option parameter. A constraint like the one [described here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jasonconway/archive/2009/10/23/include-and-exclude-constraints-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx). However every time you add /rename an action you will need to update that list...

Comment: @DanielJ.G., I'm pondering on using constraints as we speak (or in this care _as we type_).

Comment: I don't like that solution too much, but I cannot think of any other one without changing the urls. Let's see if somebody else comes with a different approach!

Comment: @DanielJ.G., I don't like it either and at this point I think I like it less than creating that _helper_ controller.